# Wordpress PHP code for printing child theme directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to use this code `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` to print out the directory reference to my child theme in Wordpress. It goes to the parent theme instead. Reading the codex here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri it appears as though it should retrieve the directory for the child theme if one has been designated.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `get_stylesheet_directory();`. This will go to the current theme, child or parent.

`get_template_directory();` will still go to the parent theme if you are using a child theme.

Comment: ahh thanks. Rookie error. I was not properly reading the difference in the code. Thanks. Time to rest these eyes...